# Concatenate function in Excel 2010 to add single quotes and commas

Tags: excel

I am working on a loaner laptop and have found that the concatenate function I have used to add single quotes and a comma to a column of text is no longer working. I need this to bring a series of IDs into a SQL query. The function I  have used for years is =concatenate("'",A1,"',") to get a result of 'A1',. This is in Microsoft Excel 2010.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try the following as an alternative to =concatenate():

```
="'"&A1&"',"
```

I've been using the above to do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! So strange that something I have been using for over 10 years just stopped working :-)

Answer (score 6):

Follow the below steps.

1- select all the rows.

2- right click and select format cells

3- select number tab

4- select custom in the left category tab and

5- under the type enter '@' (if column has hello after applying format it will turn into 'hello')

Answer (score 6):

Use Excel Characters.
In your case it would be :

```
= concatenate(CHAR(39),A1,CHAR(39))
```

To get the result = 'A1'

similarly, you can include other special charterers as well. Like to include space you need to use CHAR(32).

Comment: Here is the list of other special character codes:https://excelx.com/characters/list/

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `textjoin()` function is not in Excel 2010 but if someone is wondering how to concatenate several columns, wrapping the values in a single quote in the latest Excel versions just run this:

`=TEXTJOIN(delimeter, ignore empty cells (true|false), usual range of cells)`

I used something like this to create a sql script to insert values in a table:

`="INSERT INTO my_table values ('" & TEXTJOIN("','", False, A2:Z2) & "')"`

check the official [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

To enclose all specified cells in quotes, the following simple formulas may help you.

**Method 1:**

Use below formula into the blank cell:

```
=CHAR(34) & A1 & CHAR(34)
```

> Considering the value that you want to enclose in quotes is present in A1 cell

**Method 2:**

To insert single quotes around the cell values, use this formula:

```
 ="'" & A1 & "'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply put single quote inside double quotes when you need to concat it with any other string.
for example: concat("'", "A", "'") will give you 'A'.

In other words you treat it like any other character that you use in concat.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30987400)

Comment: Sometimes I find single is enough to answer question. It becomes a subjective matter whether you like the answer or not.